# Loop before launching function

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I would like to run a function with different parameters each time. But instead of looping on each fruit and launch the function it will just loop all fruits AND run the function without parameters.

```
export async function runTestForAll() {
  var fruits = require('./fruits.json');
  var fruitsArray = Object.keys(fruits);
  var arrayLength = fruitsArray.length;    

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(fruitsArray[i])
    fruits = fruitArray[i]
    runTest(fruits)
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have any information about what this `runTest` function is doing so we don't have much to go off here. Are you trying to call call runTest on each iteration with that fruit? If so, this code will work.

I've also noticed that the function is asnyc. Are you missing an `await`?

```
export async function runTestForAll() {
    var fruits = require('./fruits.json');

    for (index in fruits) {
        var currentFruit = fruits[index];
        await runTest(currentFruit)
    }
}
```

Assuming that your `fruits` variable is an array of objects, it will pass each object into the function

Comment: Yes that's the goal but it will loop all fruits before running the test

Comment: Do you mean the goal is for it to loop all fruits before running the test or you it's currently doing that but it shouldn't? This is an async function - are you missing `await` before runTest?

Comment: if I add await before runtest I'll get 'ReferenceError: fixture is not defined
'